# Accessing a variable from inside an override function and using it in some other function

Tags: java, android, import

I am making a weather app by using sunshine app project of udacity,it updates weather based on user's current location.I want to set current location as default and let user change it in preferences,if user does not change location in preferences it will detect location by default and set it.I am using location manager and setting the default value in preferences.Problem is both have different scope.This is the code snippet of preferecnces.

```
   public static String getPreferredLocation(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
            context.getString(R.string.pref_location_default));

}
```

And this is where i am using locationlistener to get current city name

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
    Log.v(TAG, longitude);
    String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
    Log.v(TAG, latitude);
    String cityName = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to replace pref_location_default with cityname.But I can't access cityname outside onLoctionChanged function.I can't use it in the preferedlocation default.These all are implemented in same class, here is the complete code of the class.

**Utility.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class Utility extends Activity implements LocationListener {





public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd";

public static String getPreferredLocation(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
            context.getString(R.string.pref_location_default));

}

public static boolean isMetric(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
            context.getString(R.string.pref_units_metric))
            .equals(context.getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));
}

public static String formatTemperature(Context context, double temperature) {
    // Data stored in Celsius by default.  If user prefers to see in Fahrenheit, convert
    // the values here.
    String suffix = "\u00B0";
    if (!isMetric(context)) {
        temperature = (temperature * 1.8) + 32;
    }

    // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
    return String.format(context.getString(R.string.format_temperature), temperature);
}

static String formatDate(long dateInMilliseconds) {
    Date date = new Date(dateInMilliseconds);
    return DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
}

/**
 * Helper method to convert the database representation of the date into something to display
 * to users.  As classy and polished a user experience as "20140102" is, we can do better.
 *
 * @param context      Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The date in milliseconds
 * @return a user-friendly representation of the date.
 */
public static String getFriendlyDayString(Context context, long dateInMillis) {
    // The day string for forecast uses the following logic:
    // For today: "Today, June 8"
    // For tomorrow:  "Tomorrow"
    // For the next 5 days: "Wednesday" (just the day name)
    // For all days after that: "Mon Jun 8"

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(dateInMillis, time.gmtoff);
    int currentJulianDay = Time.getJulianDay(currentTime, time.gmtoff);

    // If the date we're building the String for is today's date, the format
    // is "Today, June 24"
    if (julianDay == currentJulianDay) {
        String today = context.getString(R.string.today);
        int formatId = R.string.format_full_friendly_date;
        return String.format(context.getString(
                formatId,
                today,
                getFormattedMonthDay(context, dateInMillis)));
    } else if (julianDay < currentJulianDay + 7) {
        // If the input date is less than a week in the future, just return the day name.
        return getDayName(context, dateInMillis);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, use the form "Mon Jun 3"
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(dateInMillis);
    }
}

/**
 * Given a day, returns just the name to use for that day.
 * E.g "today", "tomorrow", "wednesday".
 *
 * @param context      Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The date in milliseconds
 * @return
 */
public static String getDayName(Context context, long dateInMillis) {
    // If the date is today, return the localized version of "Today" instead of the actual
    // day name.

    Time t = new Time();
    t.setToNow();
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(dateInMillis, t.gmtoff);
    int currentJulianDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), t.gmtoff);
    if (julianDay == currentJulianDay) {
        return context.getString(R.string.today);
    } else if (julianDay == currentJulianDay + 1) {
        return context.getString(R.string.tomorrow);
    } else {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        // Otherwise, the format is just the day of the week (e.g "Wednesday".
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        return dayFormat.format(dateInMillis);
    }
}

/**
 * Converts db date format to the format "Month day", e.g "June 24".
 *
 * @param context      Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The db formatted date string, expected to be of the form specified
 *                     in Utility.DATE_FORMAT
 * @return The day in the form of a string formatted "December 6"
 */
public static String getFormattedMonthDay(Context context, long dateInMillis) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Utility.DATE_FORMAT);
    SimpleDateFormat monthDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
    String monthDayString = monthDayFormat.format(dateInMillis);
    return monthDayString;
}

public static String getFormattedWind(Context context, float windSpeed, float degrees) {
    int windFormat;
    if (Utility.isMetric(context)) {
        windFormat = R.string.format_wind_kmh;
    } else {
        windFormat = R.string.format_wind_mph;
        windSpeed = .621371192237334f * windSpeed;
    }

    // From wind direction in degrees, determine compass direction as a string (e.g NW)
    // You know what's fun, writing really long if/else statements with tons of possible
    // conditions.  Seriously, try it!
    String direction = "Unknown";
    if (degrees >= 337.5 || degrees < 22.5) {
        direction = "N";
    } else if (degrees >= 22.5 && degrees < 67.5) {
        direction = "NE";
    } else if (degrees >= 67.5 && degrees < 112.5) {
        direction = "E";
    } else if (degrees >= 112.5 && degrees < 157.5) {
        direction = "SE";
    } else if (degrees >= 157.5 && degrees < 202.5) {
        direction = "S";
    } else if (degrees >= 202.5 && degrees < 247.5) {
        direction = "SW";
    } else if (degrees >= 247.5 && degrees < 292.5) {
        direction = "W";
    } else if (degrees >= 292.5 && degrees < 337.5) {
        direction = "NW";
    }
    return String.format(context.getString(windFormat), windSpeed, direction);
}

/**
 * Helper method to provide the icon resource id according to the weather condition id returned
 * by the OpenWeatherMap call.
 *
 * @param weatherId from OpenWeatherMap API response
 * @return resource id for the corresponding icon. -1 if no relation is found.
 */
public static int getIconResourceForWeatherCondition(int weatherId) {
    // Based on weather code data found at:
    // http://bugs.openweathermap.org/projects/api/wiki/Weather_Condition_Codes
    if (weatherId >= 200 && weatherId <= 232) {
        return R.drawable.ic_storm;
    } else if (weatherId >= 300 && weatherId <= 321) {
        return R.drawable.ic_light_rain;
    } else if (weatherId >= 500 && weatherId <= 504) {
        return R.drawable.ic_rain;
    } else if (weatherId == 511) {
        return R.drawable.ic_snow;
    } else if (weatherId >= 520 && weatherId <= 531) {
        return R.drawable.ic_rain;
    } else if (weatherId >= 600 && weatherId <= 622) {
        return R.drawable.ic_snow;
    } else if (weatherId >= 701 && weatherId <= 761) {
        return R.drawable.ic_fog;
    } else if (weatherId == 761 || weatherId == 781) {
        return R.drawable.ic_storm;
    } else if (weatherId == 800) {
        return R.drawable.ic_clear;
    } else if (weatherId == 801) {
        return R.drawable.ic_light_clouds;
    } else if (weatherId >= 802 && weatherId <= 804) {
        return R.drawable.ic_cloudy;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Helper method to provide the art resource id according to the weather condition id returned
 * by the OpenWeatherMap call.
 *
 * @param weatherId from OpenWeatherMap API response
 * @return resource id for the corresponding icon. -1 if no relation is found.
 */
public static int getArtResourceForWeatherCondition(int weatherId) {
    // Based on weather code data found at:
    // http://bugs.openweathermap.org/projects/api/wiki/Weather_Condition_Codes
    if (weatherId >= 200 && weatherId <= 232) {
        return R.drawable.art_storm;
    } else if (weatherId >= 300 && weatherId <= 321) {
        return R.drawable.art_light_rain;
    } else if (weatherId >= 500 && weatherId <= 504) {
        return R.drawable.art_rain;
    } else if (weatherId == 511) {
        return R.drawable.art_snow;
    } else if (weatherId >= 520 && weatherId <= 531) {
        return R.drawable.art_rain;
    } else if (weatherId >= 600 && weatherId <= 622) {
        return R.drawable.art_snow;
    } else if (weatherId >= 701 && weatherId <= 761) {
        return R.drawable.art_fog;
    } else if (weatherId == 761 || weatherId == 781) {
        return R.drawable.art_storm;
    } else if (weatherId == 800) {
        return R.drawable.art_clear;
    } else if (weatherId == 801) {
        return R.drawable.art_light_clouds;
    } else if (weatherId >= 802 && weatherId <= 804) {
        return R.drawable.art_clouds;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Helper method to provide the art resource id according to the weather condition id returned
 * by the OpenWeatherMap call.
 *
 * @param weatherId from OpenWeatherMap API response
 * @return resource id for the corresponding icon. -1 if no relation is found.
 */
public static int getColorRessourceForWeatherCondition(int weatherId) {
    // Based on weather code data found at:
    // http://bugs.openweathermap.org/projects/api/wiki/Weather_Condition_Codes
    return -1;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
    Log.v(TAG, longitude);
    String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
    Log.v(TAG, latitude);
    String cityName = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define String as a field in your utility.java class outside the method so that it can be accessed elsewhere you want.

you can declare it outside the method as

```
public String cityName;
```